# I’m using a project which is expecting Python3. How can use that without messing anything up?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I’m using a project which is calling a script where `python` means python3. However python -V shows version 2. I know I have both versions (python3 -V, shows expected version) installed.

How can I run a script from this project and it run the correct version of Python?  I suspect I shouldn’t have to change anything like aliases or environment paths.  Although I haven’t used them before, this sounds exactly like what a virtual env is for.  Am I correct?

ETA:

I’m calling a script from the command line:

> make foobar

Comment: Python has no concept of "projects" so you muse be using an IDE of some sort and the answer to your question depends on which on it is. Please [edit] your question and add this missing information

Comment: You’re incorrect.  I’m just using a script that I’m calling that I got from a cloned repo. I’m using the command line btw.

Comment: The source of the script(s) that make up the so-called "project" don't matter.

Comment: It depends very much on how you are running the script. If you are on linux/macos and the script has a shebang line, change it to use python3. On windows you should use `python3 script.py`. Alternative, you can set PATH to find python3 first.

Comment: But I’m not using an IDE as you surmised

Answer (score 0):

Set your desired Python version on the IDE and create a virtualenv if especiall the project requires certain packages/libraries to keep it isolated and not run into certain errors down the road.